# How do I get relations in GraphQL?

Tags: graphql, prisma

I have the following data model in prisma.

```
type User {
  id: ID! @unique
  name: String!
  email: String! @unique
  password: String!
  ...etc
  userTypeA: UserTypeA @relation(name: "UserOnUserTypeA")
  userTypeB: UserTypeB @relation(name: "UserOnUserTypeB")
}

type UserTypeA {
  id: ID! @unique
  user: User @relation(name: "UserOnUserTypeA")
  userTypeB: [userTypeB!]!
}

type UserTypeB {
  id: ID! @unique
  user: User @relation(name: "UserOnUserTypeB")
  userTypeA: UserTypeA!
  ...etc
}
```

I also have 2 resolvers, one for registration which returns only UserTypeA and one for login which returns any kind of user.

```
async register(parent, args, ctx, info) {
    args.email = args.email.toLowerCase();
    const password = await bcrypt.hash(args.password, 10);
    const user = await ctx.db.mutation.createUser(
      {
        data: {
          ...args,
          password
        }
      },
      info
    );
    const userTypeA = await ctx.db.mutation.createUserTypeA(
      {
        data: {
          user: {
            connect: {
              id: user.id
            }
          }
        }
      },
      info
    );
    const token = jwt.sign({ userId: userTypeA.id }, process.env.APP_SECRET);
    ctx.response.cookie("token", token, {
      httpOnly: true,
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365
    });
    return userTypeA;
  },

async login(parent, { email, password }, ctx, info) {
    const user = await ctx.db.query.user({ where: { email: email } });
    if (!user) {
      throw new Error("No user found");
    }
    const valid = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (!valid) {
      throw new Error("Invalid Password!");
    }
    const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user.id }, process.env.APP_SECRET);
    ctx.response.cookie("token", token, {
      httpOnly: true,
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365
    });
    return user;
  },
```

The register mutation correctly returns a UserTypeA and nested I can find information from the User model. However when I use the login mutation I get information about the user but the nested UserTypeA comes as null.

In a tutorial by Wes Bos [Advanced React](https://www.advancedreact.com) where he makes a Full-Stack Application with React and GraphQL/Prisma (an online shop) he uses the same resolvers and gets the nested information about the user (like cart items) which are defined in the model as relations.

PS. Keep in mind that I'm a GraphQL/Prisma newbie. Thanks!

Comment: I think you have to write query resolvers  for UserTypeA and UserTypeB